# Is there a way I can fix this VueJS and axios issue "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have tried all solutions here and am getting the same error. I must be doing something wrong.

I want to use Axios globally and not have to import it in every component I need to use it. So I created its Instance, attached it to the Vue app and am still getting

```sh
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"
    
    found in
    
    ---> <Home> at src/views/app/Home.vue
           <AppLayout> at src/layouts/AppLayout.vue
             <Index> at src/views/app/index.vue
               <App> at src/App.vue
                 <Root>
```

Here is the instance that i'm creating called `axios-instance.js`

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import Vue from "vue";
import {apiUrl} from "./constants/config";

const devInstance = createInstance(apiUrl);
// const productionInstance = createInstance("http://localhost:3000"); // will change later

function createInstance(baseURL){
  return axios.create({
    baseURL,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer 9|b4DWuYCXyEK1H07KB1iiGXyRk2auEl5m1okDVe4B' //`Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
    }
  });
}

export default {
  install () {
    Vue.prototype.$http = devInstance
  }
};
```

Then inside the main.js file, I am importing the instance and attaching it to Vue using Vue.use, see below.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import http from './axios-instance';

//...

//setup axios
Vue.use(http)

//...
```

After that, I am trying to use it in an action but it's failing with the error message I showed you up there. Here is how am using it in action

```js
//...

getDashboard({commit}) {
    //get home info
    this.$http.get('sacco/home')
    .then(({status, data}) => {
        console.log(status, data)
        // commit('updateDashBoard', payload);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}

//...
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've written plugins for Vue, but if I remember correctly you need to bind to the instance passed to `install()`, not the import: `install(Vue) { Vue.prototype.$http = devInstance; }` See [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin) for more details.

Comment: @Etheryte Any idea how I can avoid the plugin completely and get it to work globally?